# Неужели правильно "гЕнезис"?

Tags: фонетика

Недавно попалось упоминание, что правильно говорить не "генЕзис", а "гЕнезис". Неужели это правильно? Так, по-моему, вообще никто не говорит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Г***Е***незис, конечно. Хотя некоторые словари допускают с разной степенью нормативности и генЕзис.
Впрочем, с ударением в этом слове вообще интересная штука происходит.

Сначала оно явно испытывало тенденции к смещению с первого слога на второй, что и нашло отражение в разных словарях. Можно было предположить, что ударение реально переместилось и этот вариант скоро станет допустимым. Справедливости ради упомяну, что орфоэпические словари никогда не давали вариант генЕзис как сколько-нибудь нормативный хотя бы на уровне разговорности (максимум - как распространенная ошибка).

Однако сейчас, возможно под влиянием английского, вариант гЕнезис отвоевывает позиции.

*Такое бывает с научной терминологией. Нечто подобное произошло, например, со словом фенОмен. не так давно все говорили феномЕн даже в тех значениях, когда это никак не допускалось нормативными словарями. Сейчас ударение на последний слог делается уже значительно реже.*

Comment: У нас в городе есть частная клиника "Генезис", так в рекламе говорят только с ударением на второе Е. Кроме того, я биолог, поэтому слово это слушать доводилось очень часто от разных преподавателей — и тоже всегда с ударением на втором Е.

Answer (score 3):

Литературная норма только г**е**незис, правда с ударением на второй слог, слово уже фиксируют, но пока лишь как разговорный вариант.

Если вы считаете, что так никто не говорит, то зря. Я, например, до сегодняшнего дня о никаких "ген**е**зисах" не слышал, хотя при изучении истории это слово употребляют нередко.

Answer (score 0):

Лично мне приходилось часто слышать как вариант произношения с ударением на первом слоге, так и с ударением на втором. Сложилось ощущение, что произносят "ге'незис" чаще все-таки люди, работающие с языками (русским, английским, латинским и греческим). А вот люди (даже из сферы науки, но из других областей: философии, психологии, физики), не связанные с языками, частенько говорят "гене'зис". Про рекламщиков и говорить не приходится, они все и "марке'тинг" произносят... ))

Отвечая, собственно, на сам вопрос: считаю, что правильно говорить именно "ге'незис".